# Figuring out difference between these two queries involving datetime

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I was going through bigquery's chicago taxi data. I expected to get two of the same answers from these two codes.  Note that trip_start_timestamp is originally in datetime format (e.g 2015-12-23 00:00:00 UTC)

```
SELECT
   COUNT(DISTINCT unique_key) AS num_trips
FROM
  `bigquery-public-data.chicago_taxi_trips.taxi_trips`
WHERE  
trip_start_timestamp >= '2015-12-23'
and 
trip_start_timestamp <= '2015-12-27'

SELECT
  COUNT(DISTINCT unique_key) AS num_trips
FROM
  `bigquery-public-data.chicago_taxi_trips.taxi_trips`
WHERE  
cast(trip_start_timestamp as date) >= '2015-12-23'
and 
cast(trip_start_timestamp as date) <= '2015-12-27'
```

I tried to see if they were the same by looking at this code:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(DISTINCT unique_key) AS num_trips, trip_start_timestamp
 FROM
      `bigquery-public-data.chicago_taxi_trips.taxi_trips`
    WHERE  
     trip_start_timestamp >= '2015-12-23'
     and 
     trip_start_timestamp <= '2015-12-27'
GROUP BY trip_start_timestamp 
ORDER BY trip_start_timestamp
```

This produces [image]

Then simply changing the WHERE condition with the CAST(trip_start_timestamp as date) variant. The tables look exactly the same.

Yet the end results between the first 2 codes is 150,000 results vs 200,000. Can anyone note why there might be a difference?

Comment: Can you add the sample data and table

Comment: @rami added a picture. Let me know if I should add more.

Comment: @NimbleTortoise . . . They are not the same at all.  The date '2015-12-27' as a timestamp is really '2015-12-27 00:00:00', so the timestamp comparison misses all non-midnight times from that date.

Comment: @Mikhail Berlyant  Thank you for letting me know, I have updated the votes here. Quite new around here.

Comment: @NimbleTortoise - see https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up for how to vote up :o)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All records with timestamp for '2015-12-27' date - like for example '2015-12-27 06:15:00 UTC' - are considered > then '2015-12-27' which I would expect you agree make sense
At the same time when you CAST such timestamp to DATE it "becomes" a 2015-12-27 which is obviously = '2015-12-27'

So, there are 45,413 such records, which is exactly difference between the two results.
Because for such records below WHERE clause is false

```
WHERE trip_start_timestamp >= '2015-12-23'
and trip_start_timestamp <= '2015-12-27'
```

Below are simplified examples of above effect

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT TIMESTAMP('2015-12-27 06:15:00 UTC') trip_start_timestamp UNION ALL
  SELECT TIMESTAMP('2015-12-26 06:15:00 UTC')
)
SELECT *
FROM `project.dataset.table`
WHERE trip_start_timestamp >= '2015-12-23'
AND trip_start_timestamp <= '2015-12-27'
```

returns **ONLY ONE** record

```
Row trip_start_timestamp     
1   2015-12-26 06:15:00 UTC
```

while

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT TIMESTAMP('2015-12-27 06:15:00 UTC') trip_start_timestamp UNION ALL
  SELECT TIMESTAMP('2015-12-26 06:15:00 UTC')
)
SELECT *
FROM `project.dataset.table`
WHERE CAST(trip_start_timestamp AS DATE) >= '2015-12-23'
AND CAST(trip_start_timestamp AS DATE) <= '2015-12-27'
```

returns **ALL Two** records

```
Row trip_start_timestamp     
1   2015-12-27 06:15:00 UTC  
2   2015-12-26 06:15:00 UTC
```

This is because timestamp '2015-12-27 06:15:00 UTC' is considered greater than '2015-12-27' and as such is excluded from result of first query

Hope this simplified example will help :o)

Comment: Why would the 2nd query give more results? I believed it should be more restrictive because I initially thought if you use CAST() in the WHERE condition, it will only look at 2015-12-26, 2015-12-27, etc. and not 2015-12-26 00:00:01, 2015-12-25 00:00:02, etc. My last query shows they produce identical tables for the first 100 rows at least. So there must be something about unique_keys I am not understanding.

Comment: Please read again my answer, it explains exactly why this happens!

Comment: So let me see if I understand your point. If I use cast(2015-12-25) as >=, I am counting results that are both 2015-12-25 00:00:00 UTC and 2015-12-25? Whereas with just timestamp, it would only count results with a full timestamp? So there are 50,000 results that are exactly 2015-12-25, 2015-12-26, 2015-12-27, etc.? I may be confused because I view 2015-12-25 as the same thing as 2015-12-25 00:00:00.

Comment: No, that is not what my point is. Let me add some simple example for you in my answer. Check it in about 5-10 min

Comment: So if I have 2015-12-25 03:33:33, SQL will also consider that as having satisfied the 2015-12-25 equal condition for CAST statement where-condition? So therefore, will have more results. I thought count(distinct(unique_keys)) would essentially render this difference null.

Comment: Now you are closer to the point I made. See addition to my answer. And again - this has nothing to do with count(distinct(unique_keys)) itself

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant . . . I think there is a simpler way to explain it.  When you compare timestamps, '2015-12-27' is '2015-12-27 00:00:00', so it does not include data  from that date.  When you compare as dates, the full date is compared -- and only the date -- so all times on the date are included.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - agree. I thought my initial version was simple enough - but now I see  - this would be simpler